# Simple way to hide and show element with svelte

Tags: javascript, web, frameworks, svelte, astrojs

I want to have a simple with way to hide and show an element with a button on svelte, how can I do it? Also is it simpler to do it in vanilla JS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this code worked for me, it is a modified version of an example provided by Svelte which can be found [here](https://svelte.dev/examples/event-modifiers)

```
<script>
    let visible = true;

    function toggleVissible() {
        visible = !visible
    }
</script>

<button on:click={toggleVissible}>
    Hide
</button>

{#if visible}
    <p>
        This text will hide.
    </p>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 5):

Svelte has the [`{#if}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-if) directive for that, which can be tied to local state, which in turn can be changed via a button's `on:click`.

Whether it is easier in vanilla JS depends on many things, including the overall complexity. In the long run, things tend to be easier with Svelte.

I would recommend doing [the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial)...

Answer (score 0):

### Vanilla

Here is one way to do it in vanilla JS.

You can directly place this inside an `.astro` component:

```html
<button>Toggle</button>

<p>Content</p>

<script>
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
        const el = document.querySelector('p')
        el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'
    }
</script>
```

---

### Svelte

And here is one example doing it in svelte:

```html
<script>
  let toggle = true
</script>

<button on:click={() => (toggle = !toggle)}> Toggle </button>

{#if toggle}
  <p>Content</p>
{/if}
```

Make sure to import it with a `client:` directive to get the JS actually shipped to the client in astro:

```astro
---
import Svelte from "./svelte.svelte";
---

<Svelte client:load />
```

---

### Which one to choose?

I would recommend going with svelte, since it's so more readable, and you also have a better scalability, when you plan to add more features in the future.